# Compression in Android taking long time

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I am new to Video related operations. I am using [FFMPEG][1] to compress a video in my Android application.

I am trying to compress a video of 50MB to 10MB by executing following command

```
ffmpeg -y -i /videos/in.mp4 -strict experimental -s 640x480 -r 25 -vcodec mpeg4 -b 150k -ab 48000 -ac 2 -ar 22050 /videos/out.mp4
```

Video compressing successfully, but it taking more than 150 seconds. I am unable find out how to reduce that time.

I want to change this command to complete this process in less time.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do much here,few things you can try :

1. you can set the -preset value to fast/veryfast/ultrafast
   you can set the -crf value (usually 18 to 28).
2. If you do not want to alter your audio/video codecs, you should retain the original settings using: -c copy (this can drastically improve the execution time, depending upon your use-case)

Also read this :https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java/issues/54

3.possibly use x264 "ultrafast" options (you can set the -preset value to fast/veryfast/ultrafast), or if you want mp4 video codec, maybe decrease the resolution or some option it allows

Comment: It *appears* that NSR wants MPEG-4 Part 2 video, not H.264 video, so the `-crf` and `-preset` suggestions will not be applicable to the encoder `mpeg4` which is being used in the question.