# Need fast video compression with quality also

Tags: android

I am trying to compress the video but not able to compress fast way....using follow dependency also **silicompressor** /**Video Compressor and Compressor**..
The above list of compressor working fine but taking too much of time based on the video selection (For ex : if i select 2 MB video ~3 to 4 minute taking for compression)

```
class VideoCompressAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        Context mContext;

        String path = File path;

        File directory = new File(path);

        public VideoCompressAsyncTask(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            showProgress();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... paths) {
            String filePath = null;
            try {

                filePath = SiliCompressor.with(mContext).compressVideo(myUrl, directory.getPath(), 0, 0, 0);

            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return filePath;

        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String compressedFilePath) {
            super.onPostExecute(compressedFilePath);
            File imageFile = new File(compressedFilePath);

        }
    }
```

Taking to much of time for video compression

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compression in Android taking long time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43580185/compression-in-android-taking-long-time)

Comment: _if i select 2 MB video ~3 to 4 minute taking for compression_ I don't think so it will take too much time.

Comment: https://github.com/tcking/GiraffeCompressor have you checked it?

Comment: i tried GiraffeCompressor..this is also taking too much time based on video selection size

Comment: Have you checked net connection? Because i have used the _VideoCompressor_ lib which works perfectly event 5- 10 MB video

Comment: VideoCompressTask task = VideoCompress.compressVideoMedium (tv_input.getText().toString(), destPath, new VideoCompress.CompressListener() ..
I was using the above code by using videocompressor but couldn't give quick compression..it takes long period of time ~2 to 3 minutes